# Is there an integer A such that it has exactly X positive integer divisors and exactly K of them are prime numbers?

Tags: c++, factors, prime-factoring, number-theory

I need to determine whether there is an integer A such that it has exactly X positive integer divisors and exactly K of them are prime numbers. We will be given T testcases.

> e.g T = 1, X = 4 and K = 2

```
Then we get A = 6 which has exactly 4 factors: 1, 2, 3 and 6.
Exactly 2 of them are prime: 2, 3
```

Constraints:

> 1 ≤ T ≤ 10^3
>
> 1 ≤ X,K ≤ 10^9

As the X and K constraints are very big, brute force checking will not work I guess.

Comment: This will help: https://youtu.be/mlVKrgED-Vc

Comment: Right now this is more math-oriented (and should therefore be on [the math SE site](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) than programming oriented. Can you please [edit] your question to be more about programming (as detailed in [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the section named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). I also recommend that you read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I added the constraints.

Comment: I would also have recommended moving the question to math.stackexchange.com, were it not that the c++ tag is there, and there is no question posed. This indicates that @HarryPotter would like us to [write his software for him. That's not what stackoverflow is for. Sorry.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is purely about math, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

Asking this question here violates the Codechef's code of conduct as this is a problem statement of a question from a live contest "April Long Challenge". [Here's the link to this problem](https://www.codechef.com/APRIL20B/problems/STRNO)
Kindly don't ask such questions before the live contest ends.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a part of Ongoing **Codechef April Long Challenge 2020**.
Question Link : [Question[][1]](https://www.codechef.com/APRIL20B/problems/STRNO)
And Hence it should not be asked directly in this portal.This violated the Codechef Code of Conduct and User may be banned by Codechef.
In future ,Please avoid asking question from an Ongoing Coding Challenge.